# "mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/anaconda’:Permission denied"

Tags: software-installation, datascience-anaconda

I just installed Ubuntu.
I downloaded the anaconda python package and am trying to install it,

```
bash Anaconda-2.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

at some point the terminal says:

```
Anaconda will now be installed into this location:
/home/*username*/anaconda

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify an different location below
```

So I wanted to install in `/opt` (which I heard was an appropriate directory), but the terminal then says:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/anaconda’:Permission denied
ERROR: Could not create directory: /opt/anaconda
```

I don't see how I can use `sudo` here as the installer runs then `mkdir`.
I tried making the directory myself first, bit then it gives the fact that the dir exists as an error.
What can I do?

Comment: Try to prefix your command with `sudo `.

Comment: @Cyrus I can't, I have to fill in the directory I want to use, so with sudo this'd be >sudo /opt/anaconda
At this point the terminal complains that directories can't have spaces in them, i.e. it sees Sudo as part of the directory I'm trying to install Anaconda in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I wanted to install in `/opt`

The `/opt` directory is root owned, normal users can't write in it. As long as you tell anaconda that you want to install in directories that non-root users cannot write, you must use elevated privileges. When you start the installer, you must use sudo from the start:

```
sudo bash Anaconda-2.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh
[...]
Anaconda will now be installed into this location:
/home/user/anaconda

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify an different location below

[/home/user/anaconda] >>> /opt/anaconda
```

Anaconda doesn't write anything before that, so you can rest assured.

Comment: I thought sudo only works with the initial command, but this works.

Comment: sudo gets inherited by every subprocess.